# Ассоциативный массив JS

Tags: javascript, php

Помогите разобраться с ассоциативными массивами.
1. Как можно в массив добавить новый ключ если такого нет
2. Какой функцией можно добавить к определённому ключу значение в конец, чтобы старые значения не перезаписывать?

Comment: Если вы приведете пример из чего и во что.. мы вам покажем конкретный пример как это делается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот то же самое, что предложил предыдущий автор, но на js

```js
// Создаём объект, который будем использовать в качестве ассоциативного массива
var arr = {
  key1: 'key1_value1',
  key2: [
    'key2_value1',
    'key2_value2',
  ]
};

//  Если нет `key3`, то создадим
if (!('key3' in arr)) {
  arr.key3 = 'key3_value1';
  
}

// Добавить в конец строки
arr.key1 += '_extra';

// Добавить в конец массива
arr['key2'].push('key2_value3');

// Выведем результат
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятен вопрос, но из того что я прочитал, давайте попробуем ответить так: (p.s. примеры на `php`)

```
// Ассоциативный массив
$array = [
  'key1' => 'key1_value1',
  'key2' => [
    'key2_value1',
    'key2_value2',
  ]
];

//  Если нет `key3`, то создадим
if (!isset($array['key3'])) {
  $array['key3'] = 'key3_value1';
}

// Добавить в конец строки
$array['key1'] .= '_extra';

// Добавить в конец массива
$array['key2'][] = 'key2_value3';

// Выведем результат
var_dump($array);
```

Результат:

```
array(3) {
  ["key1"] => "key1_value1_extra"
  ["key2"] => {
    [0] => "key2_value1"
    [1] => "key2_value2"
    [2] => "key2_value3"
  }
  ["key3"] => "key3_value1"
}
```

Comment: А как на js тоже самое сделать?